# Coredata: error in constraints

Tags: swift, core-data, error-handling, constraints

I have this simple code to save an object in coredata.
In my xcatamodel I set a constraint to "firstName":
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HitjK.png). 
After deleting all entries in the "Student" Entity, the code works fine.
But only for one time.
When i´m saving the same set a second time, i´m getting "fatal error".

```
func saveStudent() {

    let student: Student = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Student", into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! Student

                student.firstName = "henry"
                student.lastName = "miller"
                student.age = 22

    DatabaseController.saveContext()
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Student> = Student.fetchRequest()

    do {
        let searchResults = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
        print("number of results: \(searchResults.count)")
        for result in searchResults as [Student] {
            print("\(result.firstName) \(result.lastName) \(result.age)")
        }
    } catch {

        print ("error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

As far as I´m understanding, the constraint is meant to recognize a potential dublicate.
Anyone an idea how to solve this problem?
Here´s the error: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnbtc.png)
For any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: That is why it is give the error:  to prevent the creation of duplicates.

Comment: Do you know how to change this function into an update function? Meaning to check dublicates, if not add the new entry, if yes, cancel the entry.

Comment: You have to do a fetch and check if it already exists.  If it does the update, if it doesn't then create.  There is no quick upsert.

Comment: it´s working now. In case the entry exists, it´s doing nothing, in case it doesn´t, it adds the entry. thanks.

Comment: NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution:

```
func saveStudent() {

    let student: Student = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Student", into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! Student

                student.firstName = "henry"
                student.lastName = "miller"
                student.age = 22

    DatabaseController.getContext().mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

    DatabaseController.saveContext()
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Student> = Student.fetchRequest()

    do {
        let searchResults = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
        print("number of results: \(searchResults.count)")
        for result in searchResults as [Student] {
            print("\(result.firstName) \(result.lastName) \(result.age)")
        }
    } catch {

        print ("error: \(error)")
    }
}
```